# How to include model's parameter in my custom loss function

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, gradient-descent, pytorch-lightning

I am using PyTorch Lightning and I defined my model like below:

> ```
> class MyModel(MyBaseClass):
>
>     def __init__(self, ..., **kwargs):
>         super().__init__(**kwargs)
>
>         self.model_parameter = nn.Parameter(
>             torch.rand(...) 
>         )
> ```

And I use a custom loss function like below:

> ```
> class MyCustomLoss(pl.LightningModule):
>     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
>         super().__init__(**kwargs)
>
>     def __call__(self, outputs, targets):
>         loss = ...
>         scalar_loss = torch.mean(loss)
>         return scalar_loss
> ```

And in my config file, I set the class_path like below:

> ```
> model:
>     class_path: ...path_to_MyModel
>     init_args:
>     criterion:
>         class_path: ...path_to_MyCustomLoss
> ```

However, I need a way to access my `model_parameter` in my custom loss function. I need these parameters to calculate my loss. How can I have my model's parameters in my custom loss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the model instance to your custom loss function. Once your custom loss function has the access to the model instance, you can pull the `model_parameters`. Here's how it works:

```
class MyCustomLoss(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, outputs, targets, model):
        # access model parameters
        model_parameter = model.model_parameter
        # proceed to calculate loss...
```

And when you call the loss function in your training step, pass the model instance:

```
class MyModel(MyBaseClass):

    def __init__(self, ..., **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.model_parameter = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(...))
        self.criterion = MyCustomLoss(...)  # Your custom loss function

    def forward(self, x):
        # define the forward pass
        ...

    def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        inputs, targets = batch
        outputs = self(inputs)
        # compute loss
        loss = self.criterion(outputs, targets, self)
        return loss
```